# using amazon s3 to host static image and referencing from css

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am trying to use s3 to upload all static images/css/js that I have. In one of my css file which is inside a css folder, I have the following:

```
background: url('../bundles/sitemain/img/bg-storefront.png') no-repeat center top;
```

and in my s3 bucket I already have the bundles folder:

[image]

With the file bg-storefront.png in the appropriate sub directory. However, is this even possible with amazon s3 such that it doesn't have the notion of what a folder is. So in this case do I have to use the absolute path of the image to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the relative path should work: when the browser interprets the parent directory `..`, it does it simply by how the URL looks. The browser/website visitor doesn't normally know anything about the actual file structure behind most web pages, and S3 is no different. If your CSS file is named `css/style.css` and you reference `../bundles/images/a.png`, it only matters (to the browser) that the URL `bundles/images/a.png` exists: it doesn't matter whether a real filesystem or directory structure backs up those URLs.